# How to get rvm running inside fcgi?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, rvm, fastcgi

I had a rails 2.3 application running on apache + fcgi, and I am migrating it to rails 3.1 + rvm (+ apache + fcgi).

I am now blocked at fcgi <-> rvm.

I tried putting `#!/usr/local/bin/rvm 1.9.2@rails31 exec ruby`inside my `public/dispatch.fcgi`.

Running `/usr/local/bin/rvm use 1.9.2@rails31 exec ruby /some_path/current/public/dispatch.fcgi` from my command line works fine, but the apache log shows:

> ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument(s): '/some_path/current/public/dispatch.fcgi ' ( see: 'rvm usage' )

Any idea of what is going on ?
How should configure things to make this work ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried myself but how about something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p180
```

following the instructions at [How to use RVM installs of Ruby in shell & CGI scripts](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/5397/how-to-use-rvm-installs-of-ruby-in-shell-cgi-scripts/)? (If you have RVM installed locally at user directory, the path would be something like ~/.rvm/bin/...