# redmine.org not running after updated the ruby

Tags: cpanel, redmine

Ruby updated to version 1.8.7 and the redmine display at the top right side "Not Running" The issue that I found is that doesn't send mailing alerts to users when the status of one task change.

The redmine save tasks normally.

Do you know why I get "Not running"?
Do you know how can I found what is not running?
Do you know how the mail alerts will work as before?

Also the redmine is hosted in cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your Ruby version is very old and non-maintaned, you should look for 2.4.x versions.

I recommend that you install new ruby via **rvm** or **rbenv**

So if you are to proceed with RVM, it's easy to install via console, it first imports the key

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

And then installs via curl and bash (your should ask for permission to use bash, because often with cpanel, the only shell users can use is some kind of jailshell)

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Once RVM is installed, you will be able to install new ruby for that particular user, by typing `rvm install rubyversion` replace rubyversion with one of your choice.

And then proceed with Redmine upgrade, as explained in manual 
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade

Once you are done with that, you must figure out, how is your redmine being served, I assume it's served as fcgi module, since it's old version of ruby, so you might have to seek for a way to run your Redmine with new ruby, I recommend to try this approach first [How to get rvm running inside fcgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875690/how-to-get-rvm-running-inside-fcgi)

There are several ways to deploy rails app like Redmine on a web-server, however running under cpanel gives you little or no choices, alternative would be to run some server like thin, or webrick, and proxy it thru apache, which should be possible with cpanel.

Comment: Thanks Aleksander,

But I am not familiar with the whole procedure. I ll try to configure out.